# using synhronize for getters/setters or AtomicReference

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, java.util.concurrent

As I understand the case like:

```
class Case1{
        private Object object;
        public synchronized Object getObject() {
            return object;
        }
        public synchronized void setObject(Object object) {
            this.object = object;
        }
    }
```

would be considered like deprecated in comparison with the:

```
class Case2{
    private AtomicReference<Object> object = new AtomicReference<Object>();
    public Object getObject() {
        return object.get();
    }
    public void setObject(Object object) {
        this.object.set(object);
    }
}
```

Am i right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases, the operation within the getter and the setter is atomic (reference assignment). So a more efficient (at least in terms of readability) idiom would be:

```
class Case3 {
    private volatile Object object = new Object();
    public Object getObject() {
        return object;
    }
    public void setObject(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

As for your actual question, `AtomicReference` provides a few simple atomic operations which would make it a good choice over volatile if you need them. And `synchronized` makes the whole block atomic, which enables you to make even more complex operations in an atomic way.

In other words, `volatile`, `AtomicReference` and `synchronized` all have their specificities and are not equivalent.

Comment: so volatile is more efficient than atomic?

Comment: @barn.gumbl AtomicReference uses a volatile variable internally but adds a layer of getters / setters, so it can't be more efficient - they are probably roughly equivalent in most situations. But volatile is certainly simpler to use for your example.

Answer (score 1):

Volatile should be sufficient. AtomicReference adds more useful operations such as getAndSet() and compareAndSet(). But if you're doing only get and set, volatile should be cheaper.